# Chrome and Firefox extension: where to store data?

Tags: json, database, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm on extension for Chrome and Firefox, which client's side should query structured informations. It could be a remote/local DB or JSON. The size of DB would be 100.000 rows x 16 columns. The size of generated JSON would be 110MB.

The query should be fired (only READ) always shortly (some milliseconds) after the client queries Google (loads a SERP). The query result should be displayed in additional `div` on the SERP page.

How could i store data to:

- get data fast,
- not to force user to download an extension sized more than 100MB

Comment: Use chrome.storage.local and add "unlimitedStorage" to "permissions" in manifest.json.

Comment: Does it mean, that user should download the extension with the whole database file and store it in localStorage?

Comment: Why? No it doesn't mean that.

Comment: I probably don't understand the question. If you want to download the data separately or generate it on the fly, you can store it in any storage available for extensions like chrome.storage.local I've mentioned above.

Comment: The data already exists - now it is placed in remote MySQL. The question is: if i query it from the clients extension part - it could take much time. If i place the data together with extension on the client's computer - the extension is too big to force user download it...

Comment: Simply offer the user to download the data separately like many popular extensions do. Then store the data in any local storage like chrome.storage.local. Easy-peasy. Anyway, there's no magical alternative solution in this universe.

Comment: thought about it, exactly on this way, but... Whould you use an extension, if it needs firstly download 100Mb database for proper working? Could you maybe give me an example of what you mean with "like many popular extensions do"?

Comment: Of course I would use such an extension if it's useful. Downloading of 100MB zipped  or lzma-compressed to 10MB or less seems a no-brainer especially if it's just once. You'll just have to include unzip.js or lzma.js in your extension. As for examples, uBlock Origin for one.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you!